# Call to a member function on a non-object on WP Plugin Page

Tags: php, wordpress, object, global-variables, scoping

I have the following code connecting to the AWS PHP SDK in the form of a Wordpress plugin page. I'm receiving the `Call to a member function on a non-object` error when trying to use the `$MTurk` variable in the last function (`bz_page_file_path`). I've attempted various solutions like $global variables, but have had no luck. I've also confirmed that the code does work if I move the contents of `bz_page_file_path` into the constructor function (so it appears to be some kind of scoping issue perhaps). What can I do to pass this to the function correctly?

```
<?php

class BZ_NamePicker {

  // Constructor
  function __construct() {

    require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/aws-autoloader.php';

    $MTurk = new Aws\MTurk\MTurkClient([
      ...
    ]);

    add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'bz_add_menu' ));
  }


  /* Action to load admin menu */

  function bz_add_menu() {

    add_menu_page('NamePicker', 'NamePicker', 'manage_options', 'namepicker-dashboard',
      array(__CLASS__, 'bz_page_file_path'),
      'dashicons-sticky','3');
  }

  /* Action to load content on admin webpage */

  function bz_page_file_path() {

    $accountBalance = $MTurk->getAccountBalance([]);
    echo $accountBalance['AvailableBalance'];
  }


}

new BZ_NamePicker();
```

Comment: try print_r($MTurk) and check, i guess its returning array and not array of objects

Comment: @Exprator it does in fact seem to be returning an object, but only when I print_r within the construct function. Using print_r within the bz_page_file_path function returns nothing.

Comment: did you tried to declare $MTurk as global $MTurk before assigning the $MTurk function? like global $MTurk; then  $MTurk = new Aws\MTurk\MTurkClient([
      ...
    ]);

Comment: @Exprator yes, I've tried that. No change in the error message.

Comment: ok inside the function call global @MTurk; means inside bz_page_file_path()

Comment: Thanks @Exprator, that did it!

Comment: great :) happy could help you up

Comment: For sure @Exprator

Comment: Thanks bro, give me a moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

class BZ_NamePicker {

  // Constructor
  function __construct() {
     global $MTurk;
    require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/aws-autoloader.php';

    $MTurk = new Aws\MTurk\MTurkClient([
      ...
    ]);

    add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'bz_add_menu' ));
  }


  /* Action to load admin menu */

  function bz_add_menu() {

    add_menu_page('NamePicker', 'NamePicker', 'manage_options', 'namepicker-dashboard',
      array(__CLASS__, 'bz_page_file_path'),
      'dashicons-sticky','3');
  }

  /* Action to load content on admin webpage */

  function bz_page_file_path() {
    global $MTurk;
    $accountBalance = $MTurk->getAccountBalance([]);
    echo $accountBalance['AvailableBalance'];
  }


}

new BZ_NamePicker();
```

you need to call the class in the function you want to access it to, as a global object

Comment: Thanks! Also had to call global $MTurk; in the constructor function as well.